# Get all emails that has been not replied

Tags: c#, outlook

In latest versions of Outlook if you reply to email, you can see under Subject and email address notification "You replied to this message on...". Also there is usually an icon, displaying that reply to this email has been sent. How I can get list of all emails that has not been replied yet? Is there some way of doing this programmatically?

I have tried following approach, but it is not filtering right items:

```
private static void GetUnrepliedEmails()
{
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
  NameSpace outlookNamespace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
  MAPIFolder inboxFolder = outlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
  Items items = inboxFolder.Items;

  foreach (dynamic item in items)
  {
    if (item is MailItem)
    {

      // Get the value of the PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME property
      DateTime lastVerbExecutionTime = DateTime.MinValue;
      foreach (ItemProperty prop in item.ItemProperties)
      {
        if (prop.Name == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10820040")
        {
          lastVerbExecutionTime = (DateTime)prop.Value;
          break;
        }
      }

      // Check if the item has been replied to
      if (lastVerbExecutionTime > DateTime.MinValue && item.ReceivedTime < lastVerbExecutionTime)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
        Console.WriteLine("---- You have replied to the message.");
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
        Console.WriteLine("You have not replied to the message.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace TestOutlookCodes
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      GetUnrepliedEmails();
    }

    private static void GetUnrepliedEmails()
    {
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
      NameSpace outlookNamespace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
      MAPIFolder inboxFolder = outlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

      // Use dynamic in case there are other than mailitems in the inbox
      foreach (dynamic item in items)
      {
        if (item is MailItem)
        {
          // Check if email has been already replied here
          bool hasBeenReplied = ...? // Items items = inboxFolder.Items.Restrict("@SQL=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10820040\" IS NULL");
          Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME` MAPI property would not be present in `MailItem.ItemProperties` collection: it only contains OOM properties. If you need to retrieve a MAPI property, use `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`

Secondly, do not loop through all items in a folder, use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` with the following query:

```cs
Items items = inboxFolder.Items.Restrict("@SQL=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10820040\" IS NULL");
```

Comment: yes, that code looks fine to me. Does it do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Yep, "IS NOT NULL" should work.

Comment: You probably need a function that takes MAPIFolder as an argument, checks that folder, and then calls itself recursively for each child folder (MAPIFolder.Folders).

Comment: You can retrieve `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME` property using MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetPropertty. If the property is not present, an exception will be raised - you need to catch it and use it as an indication that the property does not exist, and hence the message has not been replied to. But do **not** loop through all items in a folder, use `Find/FindNext` or `Restrict`.

Comment: Almost: the property name must in the DASL format.

Comment: I think I got it working, even without TRY/CATCH, but using your suggestion. You are holding one of a kind information about Outlook. Thank you once again for your help and share of your knowledge!